# Building Python 2.6 as shared library broke (after previously working), any reason why?

Tags: python, shared-libraries

I'm on a VPS running CentOS, with has Python 2.4 installed - which unfortunately means that I have to avoid breaking it. So I'm installing Python 2.6 as a separate install, then using virtualenv. Yesterday, I installed Python 2.6 with --enable-shared, so I could compile mod_wsgi - and it worked fine. Today, I had to start from scratch, and re-installed Python 2.6 as a shared library - and it broke, for reasons unknown. I'm hoping someone can tell me *why* it broke.

Note that I'm not just asking how to fix it, but why it broke. I'm pretty sure one of the answers to fixing it, will be to "set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable". I don't want to do that for two reasons. One, I didn't do it *yesterday*, and everything worked. Two, I have to avoid breaking the Python 2.4 part of CentOS, and if I add that variable to my environment via .bashrc, I'm not sure what, if anything else, might break.

#### Installing Python 2.6

```
deleted/created all relevant directories, not just *make clean*
tar -xzvf Python-2.6.6.tgz
./configure --prefix=/foo/python26 --enable-shared
make
make altinstall
```

Everything *seemed* to work, there were no obvious errors in the make outputs. Just that Python wouldn't run.

#### Hiding a library in plain sight

```
bin/python2.6: error while loading shared libraries: libpython2.6.so.1.0: 
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

[/foo/python26/lib]# ls -l
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      19 May 27 15:09 libpython2.6.so -> libpython2.6.so.1.0*
    -r-xr-xr-x  1 root root 5624403 May 27 15:09 libpython2.6.so.1.0*
    drwxr-xr-x 25 root root   20480 May 27 15:09 python2.6/

[/foo/python26/bin]# ls -l
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 10142 May 27 15:09 python2.6*
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1433 May 27 15:09 python2.6-config*
    missing file! yesterday there was a 'python' linked to python2.6

[/foo/python26/bin]# ldd python2.6
    libpython2.6.so.1.0 => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002ababe46c000)
```

A third reason I don't want to set *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* is, it doesn't make any *sense*. The *make* process *created* the shared library, and copied it into the right directory. Python *knows* where it is, the file is under its own *lib* directory.

So what changed from yesterday, when it worked, to today when it's broken? I installed a few other packages, like django (which I removed) and nginx - I didn't remove nginx, but I don't see how it could have affected anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Vensky's post on installing Python 2.6](http://www.venkysblog.com/install-python264-modwsgi-and-django-on-cento), I have what seems like a fix - although I still don't understand *why* things broke, and this fix seems kludgy. But at least it's working.

Create a file with this line:

```
#/etc/ld.so.conf.d/python2.6.conf
/foo/python2.6/lib
```

Then run the `ldconfig` command, with no arguments.

Checking that it works:

```
[~]# ldconfig -p | grep python
libpython2.6.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /foo/python26/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0
libpython2.6.so (libc6,x86-64) => /foo/python26/lib/libpython2.6.so
libpython2.4.so.1.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so.1.0
libpython2.4.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib64/libpython2.4.so

[/foo/python26/bin]# ldd python2.6
libpython2.6.so.1.0 => /foo/python26/lib/libpython2.6.so.1.0 (0x00002b351dc1a000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b351dfca000)
```

Python 2.6 is definitely working, and appears to be linked to the shared library now. And it doesn't look like it should interfere with the system's Python 2.4.

Comment: You would be better of doing 'LD_RUN_PATH=/foo/python2.6/lib make' when building Python. That what the library directory is embedded within the Python executable itself and don't need LD_LIBRARY_PATH or change ld.so.conf. You will need to set same LD_RUN_PATH when building mod_wsgi as well.

Comment: Sigh... @Graham, I don't know if you saw my (deleted) comments about LD_RUN_PATH not working (I hope not :), but I've started *everything* from scratch, and tried it again, and it seems to have worked - as far as I can tell, there are no environmental variables set, and the directory *is* embedded in the Python executable.

Comment: @Graham, once again :) if you could promote your comment to answer, I'll checkmark it. After all, when you hit 10K, you get a [free toaster](http://xkcd.com/293/). :)